# AES in CTR mode. Does both parties have to know the nonce?

Tags: aes

I'm a little bit confused. 
I'm using AES in CTR mode.
Do i need an mechanism to send the nonce with the cypertext?
Or expressed differently: does every participant has to know the current nonce to encrypt/decrypt the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the nonce would be 0 as in the NIST documentation:

> In  the  recommended  usage  scenario,  the  party  encrypting  maintains  an  integer  counter, 
>   nonce
>   , 
>   initially 0, and produces the string 
>   ctr 
>   as the 128-bit string which encodes the number 
>   nonce
>   2
>   64
>   .  (In other words, 
>   nonce 
>   is regarded as a 64-bit binary number, and 
>   ctr 
>   is constructed by appending to this number 64 zero-bits.)  The 
>   number 
>   nonce
>   is incremented following each encryption. Typically, one transmits 
>   C 
>   along with a string which encodes 
>   nonce.

If you choose to use an other nonce you would have to send this to the decrypter as well. More can be found in [this NIST](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ctr/ctr-spec.pdf) document.

Comment: It should be ok to prefix the crypted message with a nonce right?